# Transform publish MeteorJS with count of show

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I try to use `limit : count` with transform observer in Meteor and don't understand how to do it without "dirty" solutions.

Code I have on Client (not all, but main part)

```
var self = this;
self.autorun(function() {
    self.subscribe('posts', Session.get('count')); // some Number like 10
}); // client
```

And on server where I try to use it

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(count){
    check(count, Number);
    let i = 0;
    var transform = function(doc) {
        console.log(i,count);
        if (i < count){  // I try something here
            doc.description = new Date();
            i++;
            return doc;
        }
        else self.ready();
    }

    var self = this;

    var observer = Posts.find().observe({
        added: function (document) {
            self.added('posts', document._id, transform(document));
        },
        changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument) {
            self.changed('posts', document._id, transform(newDocument));
        },
        removed: function (oldDocument) {
            self.removed('posts', oldDocument._id);
        }
    });

    self.onStop(function () {
        observer.stop();
    });

    self.ready();
});
```

Any idea how to limit count of shown documents with transform in publish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Posts.find({},{limit:count})` in your query.